# TypeError after 'npm update' and 'ng build -prod'

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

After updating npm modules, I tried to run `ng build -prod` which was working fine before, I keep getting the following error:

`TypeError: extractedChunk.getNumberOfModules is not a function
    at ExtractTextPlugin.<anonymous> (/Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:246:32)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (/Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:245:27)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:206:13)
    at sealPart2 (/Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:653:9)
    at next (/Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:202:11)
    at Compilation.compilation.plugin (/Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin.js:111:6)
    at next (/Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:204:14)
    at /Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:241:13
    at /Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:421:16
    at iteratorCallback (/Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:998:13)
    at /Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
    at /Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:224:15
    at /Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:421:16
    at iteratorCallback (/Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:998:13)
    at /Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
    at /Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:213:21
    at rebuilding.forEach.cb (/Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:521:29)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at callback (/Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:521:15)
    at processModuleDependencies (/Users/myUserName/dev-test/demo/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:540:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:95:7)`

Angular cli Version etc.:

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.3
node: 8.0.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.3
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.11
@angular/common: 4.4.3
@angular/compiler: 4.4.3
@angular/core: 4.4.3
@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-beta.9-0e7d2e0
@angular/forms: 4.4.3
@angular/http: 4.4.3
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.11
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.3
@angular/platform-server: 4.4.3
@angular/router: 4.4.3
@angular/cli: 1.4.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.3
typescript: 2.3.4
```

npm version: `5.4.2`

I'am stuck as I just can't find out what's really went wrong after a simple update.

Any Ideas please?

Comment: I'm also running into this issue.

Comment: Try to remove webpack from `package.json`. run `npm uninstall webpack --save-dev`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fixed it for me. (Basically if you look at the npm log during install it says extract-text-webpack-plugin requires webpack 3.1.0 dependency.

So just update your webpack, e.g:

```
npm install webpack@3.1.0 --save-dev
```

Comment: Great. This could be one more option.. sure. For me, was enough to get rid of `webpack` from `package.json` as I didn't need it there any way. The whole App is being done with `Angular CLI`, and prod is on Docker `nginx`

Comment: Yeah true, thinking I might remove carets and tidles from my package.json I can't be dealing with issues like this everytime I deploy on my production server.

Comment: @Baconbeastnz: Done

Comment: Same issue in Create React App while executing npm run build. Add webpack worked for me. Thanks doc